# Part title in TOC only

Tags: titles, parts

Article class. XeLaTeX compiler. I want the titles of parts to appear in the TOC only (not in the document itself). Is this possible?

Comment: Short answer from the duplicate: put `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{title of the part}` in the code where the part starts, and don't use an actual `\part{}` command.